# Stack Overflow stands with you

Tags: discussion

This evening, Joel Spolsky, the CEO of Stack Overflow, [posted this message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand):

> I am extremely upset by President Trump’s executive order on immigration. It is immoral, unconstitutional, and fundamentally un-American.
>
> The community on Stack Overflow is made up of users from all over the world. At least 100,000 posts on Stack Overflow were written by users from the seven countries from which President Trump has banned immigration. These posts have been viewed at least 250,000,000 times. That’s a lot of people sharing their knowledge across borders.
>
> Stack Overflow is successful because of the contributions of everyone, regardless of nationality or religion. If Stack Overflow were not a free, open, and welcoming community that ignored borders, it would never work.
>
> It’s impossible not to see the parallel: the only way to build a successful world today is to allow the contributions of everyone. Carving up the world into us vs. them, building walls, and demonizing religions, nations, and refugees is both morally repugnant and frankly stupid and counterproductive, and it goes so much against the spirit of Stack Overflow that as a community we must speak out.

I quoted it in full because some users of this site might not be active on Stack Overflow and, therefore, might not have seen it. My guess is that greater proportion of people on Islam—Stack Exchange are affected or know someone who is than any other space on our network. If that includes you, please know that we are with you. We intend for this network to be open to everyone everywhere.  I'm personally quite proud of the work you, as a community, have done to keep this a welcoming place and [resist sectarianism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/239/138).

Answer (score 12):

And we stand with Stack Overflow and its community. We have, and will, strive, to the best of our individual capabilities, to keep this place, and other like it, *open to everyone, everywhere*.

Community: You've done a lot already but we need to get past the beta phase and graduate ;)

Whoever is visiting this site for the first time, you and others alike,

**Welcome to [Islam—Stack Exchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com).**

Comment: We're not at [10 questions per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614) which is a rule of thumb for when a site is ready for graduation (we're closer to 6 questions per day, but it's rising: [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/483485/number-of-questions-per-day)).  We've only got 19 users with 3000+ reputation ([users](http://islam.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)), required to cast close votes on a graduated site, so we would be largely dependent on moderators for closure.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I'm afraid even if we would have 50 users with 3000+ reputation we would depend on moderators. Unfortunately my experience is that Muslims are somewhat lazy :(. But we could give it a try and up-vote Bleeding Fingers's posts ;)

Comment: [Please vote based on quality](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/982/3487) @Medi1Saif  :)

Comment: @BleedingFingers I try my best to do my best. Unfortunately users seem find it hard to vote at all! Often a 0 or 1+ seems to me equal to a 5+ or 10+ on other sites :S