# How do we envisage a diverse community co-existing and working together?

Tags: discussion

Judging from goldPseudo's meta post [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1868/17163), some undesirable things have happened at Islam.SE before I arrived that I'm mostly unaware of, and it's best that they don't recur.  There's also indications as per [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/17163), [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1157/17163), and [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/239/17163).  (And, yeah, my behaviour at times wasn't exactly exemplary, which I regret.)  The advice in the previous posts were at the technical level; individual steps that one could take.  I'm thinking more globally...

**Q**: How do we envisage a diverse community co-existing and working together?

When developing a plan in chess, it's helpful to think e.g. "where do I want this knight to be" ignoring how the knight would actually get there.  Once we know where we want the knight, we compare the different ways to get it there.

Likewise for this question, let's forget about how we might actually achieve harmony, but describe an idealized harmonious community.  Once we know where we want to go, it might be easier to agree on how to get there.